# How do I close a mercurial branch via SourceTree UI?

Tags: mercurial, atlassian-sourcetree

Is there a way to close a branch via the SourceTree interface, rather than via the command line for mercurial (hg)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click on the branch ***in the sidebar***, and select `Close <branch-name>...`